# Write $5 \sin \theta + 12 \cos \theta$ as a single cosine

Tags: trigonometry

> Write $5 \sin \theta + 12 \cos \theta$ as a single cosine with phase displacement.

I don't know how to start this one. If somebody could give me the formula or a sample that would be amazing!

Comment: [Here's](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039072/how-to-simpify-cos-x-sin-x/1039078#1039078) a post I wrote that might help you; it solves the general case.

Comment: And [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243747/generalization-of-sup-limits-theta-a-sin-theta-b-cos-theta-sqrt)'s a question I asked that solves a related general general case :)

Comment: Also, where did you encounter this problem? If you don't know where to start, that context would be useful.

Comment: It's the phase displacement. That's what is getting to me.

Comment: Weren't the coefficients $5$ and $12$ (instead of $20$ and $17$) like an hour ago?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have
$$5\sin(t) + 12\cos(t) = 13 \left(\dfrac5{13}\sin(t)+\dfrac{12}{13}\cos(t)\right)$$
where $13=\sqrt{5^2+12^2}$. Setting $\cos(a) = \dfrac{12}{13}$ and $\sin(a) = \dfrac5{13}$, we obtain
$$5\sin(t) + 12\cos(t) = 13 \left(\sin(a)\sin(t)+\cos(a)\cos(t)\right) = 13\cos(t-a)$$
where $a$ is such that $\cos(a) = \dfrac{12}{13}$ and $\sin(a) = \dfrac5{13}$.

Comment: Do you have to use 13 or will any number work?

Comment: @JustheBeats Has to be 13.  $\sin^2a+\cos^2a=1$.  Well, $\pm13$ anyway.

Comment: @JustheBeats : The reason it is possible to find a number $a$ for which $\sin a=1/13$ and $\cos a=12/13$ is  that $(5/13)^2+(12/13)^2=1$, and that works because $\sqrt{5^2+12^2}=13$.  That's where $13$ came from.